# Quotient of elliptic riemann surface by $\mathbb{Z}/3$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, quotient-spaces

Consider an elliptic curve $E$ and a non-zero point $a\in E$ of order three. Translation by $a$ is an automorphism $\tau_a:E\to E, x\mapsto x+a$ of order $3$ of the Riemann surface $E$. Could you please give me an idea how to get an equation of $E/G$ if an equation of $E$ is given?
In my case $E$ is given by $y^2 = x^4 + 10x^3 +25x^2 -100x.$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using Vélu's formulae; see [here](https://aghitza.org/publications/translation-velu.pdf) for a translation of his article *Isogénies entre courbes elliptiques*. These formulae have been implemented in *Magma*. Below is code for computing the equation.

First we put the curve into standard Weierstrass form with a cubic:

```
QQ := Rationals();
R<x,y> := PolynomialRing(QQ,2);
f := y^2 - (x^4 + 10*x^3 + 25*x^2 - 100*x);
C0 := Curve(Spec(R),f);
C := ProjectiveClosure(C0);
E0, mp0 := EllipticCurve(C, C![0,0,1]);
E, mp := MinimalModel(E0);
```

This gives the curve $E: y^2 + xy + y = x^3 - 76 x + 298$. Computing the torsion subgroup of $E$ with

```
T, mpT := TorsionSubgroup(E);
```

we find that the $3$-torsion of $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ consists of the points
$$
(0 : 1 : 0), \quad (2 : 11 : 1), \quad (2 : -14 : 1) \, .
$$
We then use the command `IsogenyFromKernel` to compute the isogeny, which takes as input a polynomial cutting out the $x$-coordinates of the points in our subgroup:

```
S<t> := PolynomialRing(QQ);
E2, mp2 := IsogenyFromKernel(E,t-2);
```

This returns the elliptic curve
$$
E_2 : y^2 + xy + y = x^3 + 549x - 2202 \, .
$$
We can verify that $E_2$ is $3$-isogenous to our original curve:

```
> IsIsogenous(E,E2);
true Elliptic curve isogeny from: CrvEll: E to CrvEll: E2
taking (x : y : 1) to ((x^3 - 4*x^2 - 121*x + 875) / (x^2 - 4*x + 4) : (x^3*y - 6*x^2*y + 125*x^2 + 137*x*y - 1250*x - 1508*y + 125) / (x^3 - 6*x^2 + 12*x - 8) : 1)
> _, phi := $1;
> Degree(phi);
3
```

Comment: Here is another relevant post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121561

Comment: This paper https://aghitza.org/publications/translation-velu.pdf is so perfect!